# how to correctly use json_encode with ajax

Tags: ajax, json

This doesn't look like correct json coming back in functionToHandleTheResponse. What am I doing wrong?

```
function myAjaxFunctionName() {

var post_data = $('form#formID').serialize();
console.log(post_data);

//result from console
//_wpnonce=xxxxxxx&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dtribe_events%26page%3Dtickets-attendees%26event_id%3D13764%26cxssh-hooks%3Doff&from=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com&recipients%5B%5D=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com&recipients%5B%5D=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com



$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: localizedAjax.ajax_url,
    data: {
        'action': 'myActionFunctionName',
        'post_data': post_data
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: functionToHandleTheResponse,
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log('Details: ' + desc + '\nError: ' + err);
    }
});

}

function myActionFunctionName() {

if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
    $post_data = $_REQUEST['post_data'];
}
echo json_encode($post_data);
die();     

}

function functionToHandleTheResponse(response) {

console.log(typeof response);
console.log(response);

//result from console (exactly the same as above)
//_wpnonce=xxxxxxx&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dtribe_events%26page%3Dtickets-attendees%26event_id%3D13764%26cxssh-hooks%3Doff&from=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com&recipients%5B%5D=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com&recipients%5B%5D=xxx.xxxxx%40xxxxx.com

}
```

Comment: "$.ajax" already convert the JSON received. then in `response` you have directly the JSON content. if you don't want this convertion, change `dataType` in the AJAX call.

Comment: okay. I’ll try something.